# What part of this code affects the outline?

Tags: html, css, outline

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --color-primary: #191d2b;
  --color-secondary: #27AE60;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-1: #dbe1e8;
  --color-grey-2: #b2becd;
  --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-4: #454e56;
  --color-grey-5: #2a2e35;
  --color-grey-6: #12181b;
  --br-sm-2: 14px;
  --box-shadow-1: 0 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.light-mode {
  --color-primary: #FFFFFF;
  --color-secondary: #F56692;
  --color-white: #454e56;
  --color-black: #000;
  --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-1: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-2: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
  --color-grey-4: #454e56;
  --color-grey-5: #f8f8f8;
  --color-grey-6: #12181b;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  /* transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; */
}

/* Form Size on Page */

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 3rem 18rem;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  animation: appear 2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1);
}

.text {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Email & Password Location */

.form-control {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0 40px;
  width: 300px;
}

/* Input Control Boxes */

.form-control input {
  background-color: var(--color-grey-5);
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Bottom Border Colour */

.form-control input:focus,
.form-control input:valid {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.form-control label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
}

.form-control label span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  min-width: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

/* Highlight effect */

.form-control input:focus+input span,
.form-control input:focus+input span {
  color: lightblue;
  transform: translateY(-30);
}
```

```html
<section class="container contact" id="contact">
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="main-title">
      <h2>Contact <span>Me</span><span class="bg-text"> Contact</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-content-con">
      <div class="left-contact">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="" class="contact i-c-2">
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text" required placeholder="YOUR NAME">
              <input type="email" required placeholder="YOUR EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
              <input type="text" required placeholder="ENTER SUBJECT">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
              <textarea name="" id="" cols="15" rows="8" placeholder="Message Here..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-btn">
              <a href="#" class="main-btn">
                <span class="btn-text">Download CV</span>
                <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I click on the boxes of this form the clicked box will **highlight on the outside.**

I would like to implement this on my main project but **unsure about which part of the css** code actually causes this effect to happen.

I have tried going through it one by one but even removing all of the code except body and everything above that still makes this effect work.

What part of this code lets this highlight effect happen or is there an better way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a CSS pseudo selector for "focus". You can access it like this:

```
input:focus {
   border: 1px solid red;             
}
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

Comment: You helped greatly Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad this helped out! If you wouldn't mind marking this as the accepted answer it would be greatly appreciated.